# How to ensure atomicity of a method execution in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, atomic

I have a method which calls some other methods too. These operations are NOT related to DB in any way. I am just executing some logic, making few API calls to some other external services and all. I want that all the operations must be rolled back if any exception occurs in any of the operation. How can I achieve that?

Comment: This isn't generally possible in distributed systems. You have to organize your application in a different manner, typically using _eventual consistency_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry that you have to handle it manually. For example, if exception happens , manually apply a compensation action to undo .

A pattern called saga pattern is intended for solving such problems , I quote its basic idea from [this](https://github.com/berndruecker/trip-booking-saga-java) as below:

> The Saga pattern describes how to solve distributed (business)
>   transactions without two-phase-commit as this does not scale in
>   distributed systems. The basic idea is to break the overall
>   transaction into multiple steps or activities. Only the steps
>   internally can be performed in atomic transactions but the overall
>   consistency is taken care of by the Saga. The Saga has the
>   responsibility to either get the overall business transaction
>   completed or to leave the system in a known termination state. So in
>   case of errors a business rollback procedure is applied which occurs
>   by calling compensation steps or activities in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

This might sound like an innocent question, but is in fact very tricky. What your asking for a is a distributed transaction among your API calls. For that the API counterparts would need to support something like "two-phased commit". The bottom line is: if your API providers don't support distributed transactions, you'll have to build something yourself. (Post some code, describe the method in more detail, and we'll help)

See eg. for more details: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/01/patterns-for-distributed-transactions-within-a-microservices-architecture/, or just Google "distributed transaction service calls"